# Need help reading early 20th century stock market list

Tags: history

I have a bit of a problem understanding the stock market price listings for the London stock market. I am mainly concerned with Argentinian government bonds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unfamiliar with this style of notation, but in my opinion it seems likely that the double fractions denote buy and sell prices. I.e. on Nov 29th 1911 the sell price was 104 3/8 and the buy price was 104 7/8. This gets you an average or mid price of 104 1/2 = 104.5.

It is also possible that the two numbers denote the daily opening and closing prices, but the variation seems small for this.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. I wonder though why in cases where the Times only has one figure, these figures do not always seem to match the IMM. For example, the BA Water Loan is 103 1/4 in the Times (https://imgur.com/a/vt17mWx) and 103 1/2 in the IM (https://imgur.com/a/8JhnfB7).